# Sphere-Sphere Intersection

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, intersection

I have two spheres that are intersecting, and I'm trying to find the intersection point nearest in the direction of the point (0,0,1)

My first sphere's (c1) center is at (c1x = 0, c1y = 0, c1z = 0) and has a radius of r1 = 2.0

My second sphere's (c2) center is at (c2x = 2, c2y = 0, c2z = 0) and has a radius of r2 = 2.0

I've been following the logic on [this identical question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/75756/sphere-sphere-intersection-and-circle-sphere-intersection) for the 'Typical intersections' part, but was having some trouble understanding it and was hoping someone could help me.

First I'm finding the center of intersection c_i and radius of the intersecting circle r_i:

> Here the first sphere has center c_1 and radius r_1, the second c_2 and r_2, and their intersection has center c_i and radius r_i. Let d = ||c_2 - c_1||, the distance between the spheres.

So sphere1 has center c_1 = (0,0,0) with r_1 = 2. Sphere2 has c_2 = (2,0,0) with r_2 = 2.0.

d = ||c_2 - c_1|| = 2

> h = 1/2 + (r_1^2 - r_2^2)/(2* d^2)

So now I solve the function of h like so and get 0.5:

h = .5 + (2^2 - 2^2)/(2*2^2)

h = .5 + (0)/(8)

h = 0.5

> We can sub this into our formula for c_i above to find the center of the circle of intersections.
>
> c_i = c_1 + h * (c_2 - c_1)

(this equation was my original question, but a comment on this post helped me understand to solve it for each x,y,z)

`c_i_x = c_1_x + h * (c_2_x - c_1_x)`

`c_i_x = 0 + 0.5 * (2 - 0) = 0.5 * 2`

**1 = c_i_x**

`c_i_y = c_1_y + h * (c_2_y - c_1_y)`

`c_i_y = 0 + 0.5 * (0- 0)`

**0 = c_i_y**

`c_i_z = c_1_z + h * (c_2_z - c_1_z)`

`c_i_z = 0 + 0.5 * (0 - 0)`

**0 = c_i_z**

`c_i = (c_i_x, c_i_z, c_i_z) = (1, 0, 0)`

> Then, reversing one of our earlier Pythagorean relations to find r_i:

r_i = sqrt(r_1*r_1 - h*h*d*d)

r_i = sqrt(4 - .5*.5*2*2)

r_i = sqrt(4 - 1)

r_i = sqrt(3)

r_i = 1.73205081

So if my calculations are correct, I know the circle where my two spheres intersect is centered at (1, 0, 0) and has a radius of 1.73205081

I feel somewhat confident about all the calculations above, the steps make sense as long as I didn't make any math mistakes. I know I'm getting closer but my understanding begins to weaken starting at this point. My end goal is to find an intersection point nearest to (0,0,1), and I have the circle of intersection, so I think what I need to do is find a point on that circle which is nearest to (0,0,1) right?

The next step from  [this solution](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/75756/sphere-sphere-intersection-and-circle-sphere-intersection)says:

> So, now we have the center and radius of our intersection. Now we can revolve this around the separating axis to get our full circle of solutions. The circle lies in a plane perpendicular to the separating axis, so we can take n_i = (c_2 - c_1)/d as the normal of this plane.

So finding the normal of the plane involves `n_i = (c_2 - c_1)/d`, do I need to do something similar for finding n_i for x, y, and z again?

`n_i_x = (c_2_x - c_1_x)/d = (2-0)/2 = 2/2 = 1`

`n_i_y = (c_2_y - c_1_y)/d = (0-0)/2 = 0/2 = 0`

`n_i_z = (c_2_z - c_1_z)/d = (0-0)/2 = 0/2 = 0`

> After choosing a tangent and bitangent t_i and b_i perpendicular to this normal and each other, you can write any point on this circle as: `p_i(theta) = c_i + r_i * (t_i * cos(theta) + b_i sin(theta));`

Could I choose t_i and b_i from the point I want to be nearest to? (0,0,1)

> Because of the Hairy Ball Theorem, there's no one universal way to choose the tangent/bitangent to use. My recommendation would be to pick one of the coordinate axes not parallel to n_i, and set `t_i = normalize(cross(axis, n_i))`, and `b_i = cross(t_i, n_i)` or somesuch.

Answer (score 0):

```
 c_i = c_1 + h * (c_2 - c_1)
```

This is **vector** expression, you have to write similar one for every component like this:

```
 c_i.x = c_1.x + h * (c_2.x - c_1.x)
 and similar for y and z
```

As a result, you'll get circle center coordinates:

```
c_i = (1, 0, 0)
```

As your citate says, choose axis not parallel to n vect0r- for example, y-axis, get it's direction vector `Y_dir=(0,1,0)` and multiply by n

```
 t = Y_dir x n = (0, 0, 1)
 b = n x t = (0, 1, 0)
```

Now you have two vectors `t,b` in circle plane to build circumference points.

Comment: thank you for the help, that makes sense that I would want to solve the vector expression for each x,y, and z. I updated my question to solve this step, and added my current problem to the question. I have my circle of intersection radius and center point, but I'm having a little trouble now finding the intersection point I want.

Comment: You cannot choose the closest point on the circle because all circle points are equidistant from it's center

Comment: thanks for the updated comment, so i choose an axis `y`, get its direction vector `y_dir=(0,1,0)`, i already calcualted `n_i = (1,0,0)`, so `t = y_dir * n` would be `(0,1,0) * (1,0,0)`? I think my lack in understanding on this step is why im doing this. I'm trying to get the full circle of solutions so i can find a point in that circle furthest in the direction of my hint point (0,0,1). But you say I cant choose a point on the circle because their all equidistant. Am I choosing a point on the  circumfrence of the circle to find my answer? Thank you again.

Comment: This is vector multiplication [very large page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product). You choose arbitrary point at the circle with any theta value (for example, theta=0)

Comment: okay, so im multiplying two vectors (like in the case of t=y_dir * n). How did you get (0,0,1) for (0,1,0) * (1, 0,0)? I've been trying to plug that equation in on dot product calculators online just to verify the answer before solving, like in this case: https://planetcalc.com/8244/ , but it says the dot product is zero?

Comment: Not dot but **cross** product! (In wiki link look at `coordinate/matrix notation` part) (there are some kinds of vector multiplication)

Comment: Ah that makes more sense, thank you. My overall understanding of where to go from here isnt that good. once i get the circle of intersection wouldnt i want to get all points in the circle, then find which point is nearest to my hintPoint = (0,0,1)? [thats an important piece, im trying to find the point of intersection that is furthest in the direction indicated by hintPoint]

Comment: 1) There is inifinty number of points at the circle 2)To get closest point at the circle, it is needed to solve equation with distance, not to examine a lot of points

Comment: In this specific case it is clear that closest to (0,0,1) is point at circle (1,0, 1.732)

Comment: yes I know that answer is correct, I'm just having trouble with the very very last step. my thought process is to try and fill out and solve for p_i in this function: `p_i(theta) = c_i + r_i * (t_i * cos(theta) + b_i sin(theta));` I an understand filling out values for c_i, r_i, t_i, and b_i (), but is p_i getting multiplied by the theta value I choose arbitrarily? (like theta=0?) `p_i(theta) = (1, 0, 0) + 1.73205081 * ((0, 0, 1) * cos(theta) + (0, 1, 0) sin(theta));`

Comment: Formula is right. p_i(theta) denotes function/dependence: p against theta, rather than multiplication. To walk the whole circle around, theta runs all the range 0..2*Pi